# How to display message conversation username on the URL and profile picture display from users table

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am creating two users conversation view script in PHP mysqli. My problem when I sent message as a last message my username display on the URL, therefore I want to display when I discussed other username on the URL. And also I want to display profile picture which I discussed of user profile picture, from user table.

Database pm table

```
id  from_id   from_name      to_id   to_name     msg               sent_date
1   2         john           3       master      hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3         master         2       john        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2         john           3       master      hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5         previn         2       john        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

`users` table

```
userid | username | profile_pic
```

Here is my URL

```
 <a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $guaranteed_from_id ?>&to_name=<?php echo $row['from_name'];?>">Replay</a>
```

Here is source code

```
<?php
 if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
  }

  if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ? ORDER BY sent_time DESC")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $session_id, $session_id);
    $stmt->execute();
  }

  $tempArray = array();

  $result = $stmt->get_result();

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {

          echo "<br>";
          echo $row['from_id']." - " . $row['to_id']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_time'];


        $guaranteed_from_id = str_replace($session_id, null, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);


        ?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['profile_pic'];?>" height="20px" width="20px"/>
        <a href="cons.php?to_id=<?php echo $guaranteed_from_id ?>&to_name=<?php echo $row['from_name'];?>">Replay</a>

        <?php

 }


        array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
        array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

      }
  } else {
      echo "NO MESSAGES";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you don't need to have the username in the pm table at all. So remove these columns from the "pm" table. This is because you can use the id in users table to link with the "from_id" and "to_id".

PM table:

```
id  from_id     to_id    msg               sent_date
1   2           3        hi how are you?   2019-12-05 04:14:20
2   3           2        fine              2019-12-05 05:15:58
3   2           3        hi                2019-12-05 03:20:34
4   5           2        hi                2019-12-05 08:30:40
```

Users table:

```
id    username   profile_pic         
1     john       <link to profile picture>
2     master     <link to profile picture>          
3     john       <link to profile picture>          
4     previn     <link to profile picture>
4     robin      <link to profile picture>
```

So I was thinking of using a JOIN in the SQL. But didn't really get it to work when have to select with both the to_id and the from_id. So came up with some really wierd shit. I think you have to this in some other way because this gets really wierd. But I finally did get it to work. But this is not a great solution just A solution.

The code to the solution:

```
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $session_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
      }

        $sql = "SELECT *,
  (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=from_id) AS from_username,
  (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=to_id) AS to_username,
  (SELECT username FROM users WHERE userid=?) AS my_username,
  (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=from_id) AS from_profile_pic,
  (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=to_id) AS to_profile_pic,
  (SELECT profile_pic FROM users WHERE userid=?) AS my_profile_pic
  FROM pm WHERE from_id = ? OR to_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC";


  if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
     $stmt->bind_param('iiii', $session_id, $session_id, $session_id, $session_id);
     $stmt->execute();
   }

   $tempArray = array();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {





         if (!in_array($row['to_id'].$row['from_id'], $tempArray)) {

            $friend_id = str_replace($session_id, null, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

            $title = $row['from_username'].$row['to_username'];
            $num = strlen($title) ;

            $num = $num/2;

            $first_half = substr($title,0, $num);

            $second_half = substr($title, $num);


            if ($first_half == $second_half) {
              $friend_username = $row['from_username'];
            } else {
              $friend_username = str_replace($row['my_username'], null, $row['from_username'].$row['to_username']);
            }

            $friend_profile_pic = str_replace($row['my_profile_pic'], null, $row['from_profile_pic'].$row['to_profile_pic']);

            echo "<br>";
            echo $row['from_username'] . " - " . $row['to_username']." ". $row['msg']. " - " .$row['sent_time'];

         ?>

           <img src="images/<?php echo $friend_profile_pic;?>" height="20px" width="20px"/>
           <a href="cons.php?to_name=<?php echo $friend_username ?>&to_id=<?php echo $friend_id ?>">Reply</a>

         <?php

  }


         array_push($tempArray, $row['from_id'].$row['to_id']);
         array_push($tempArray, $row['to_id'].$row['from_id']);

       }
   } else {
       echo "NO MESSAGES";
   }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203866/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-thunberg-how-to-display-message-conversation-us).

Comment: @SamuelLiew just a question how should we chat when we can't open a new chat room?

Comment: You can use comments until a mod creates a room like the above. Then you can all use the newly created room. Once the room has served its purpose, try to update the question/answer with additional details that were discussed in chat, then flag the comments as "no longer needed".

Comment: @Jonathan Thunberg can you help me